# How to add a url to startup via registry

Tags: vb.net, registry

I'm trying to add a URL to my system startup. I want to do this via the registry because it fits some other things I'm hoping to do later. Here's my code at the moment;

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\", "LinkLoad", "https://www.url.link")
```

I'm trying to do this via vb.net if at all possible. I have given the application administrative privileges but for some reason this hasn't work. The new registry key isn't in position (and to be honest I'm not 100% sure this would work in loading the webpage!).

[FYI the link in the above code is junk, I didn't think it was important to include the actual link I want to load!)

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit Windows, have you checked in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` to see if it ended up in there?

Comment: @Mark Thanks, it did end up there! It doesn't actually run the url at startup thought, is there anything I could do to change that?

Comment: Change the value to `iexplore.exe https://www.url.link/`?